# extract just the replied email body from recieved email from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

My  Rails application allows users to reply to certain emails in order to post a comment to the app. When email is replied to, the entire body including the original email gets included. Some clients put a line between the original message and the message details and some don't. I was wondering is there is a standard way to parse the email and not include the message details in the post body.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "message details"? Do you mean email headers? If so, there is only one correct/standard way to do it.

Comment: yes I mean the email headers. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at Griddler from Thoughtbot. It is supposed to work for Sendgrid but you should be able to extract the "body extraction" logic from that.   https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler

Answer (score 0):

Ideally all  the mails need to follow the RFC standards to compose the mail so that all the web browsers and clients can parse them correctly. There are soo many rfc which corresponds to it.

> MIME is specified in six linked RFC memoranda: RFC 2045, RFC 2046, RFC 2047, RFC 4288, RFC 4289 and RFC 2049, which together define the specifications

reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME

But this was the ideal scenario, some clienst appends the messages in different formats too. Am not aware of any ready-to-use software but one way which even rediffmail/yahoo uses is to parse down the mail body and search for different patterns like

> ---------- Forwarded message ----------
>
> From: xyza@gmail.com
>
> Date: 17 Feb 2013 18:50
>
> Subject: Re: Openings
>
> To: abc@rediffmail.com

or

> From: xyz [xyz@tcs.com]
>
> Sent: Wednesday, February 20, 2013 4:18 PM
>
> To: Anshul
>
> Subject: RE: Hi

It has to be a regex check and pattern matching to accomplish the desired output.